# Como utilizar diversos sites em Servidor Dedicado Ubuntu?

Tags: web-service, ubuntu

Olá, amigos!

**Contexto:** Tenho um servidor dedicado para hostear aplicações web.

- O *root directory* dele é /var/www/html padrão de qualquer server.
- Quero hostear, primeiramente, UM site.
- Na pasta root (/var/www/html) se encontra o *phpmyadmin* e o *site* (ou seja, duas pastas)
- Estou atualizando os arquivos do site via GIT, ou seja, ele tem que ficar em uma pasta separado, no caso a pasta "site". E também para usar o GIT pull e não dar problema com a pasta *phpmyadmin*

**Problema:** O problema é que TODOS os arquivos que chamo externamente, estão vindo da root, por exemploÇ

```
<link href="/css/style.css">
```

Ou seja, ele está chamando o seguinte path:

```
/var/www/html/css/style.css
```

Tem a soluções de acrescentar a pasta *site*, da seguinte forma:

```
<link href="/site/css/style.css">
```

Porém essa não é a proposta. Se fizesse assim, teria que mudar tudo em uma aplicação inteira e seria mais difícil de trabalhar localmente e colaborar com outras pessoas.

**Pergunta:** Gostaria de saber qual é o jeito certo de fazer isso e de se trabalhar, futuramente, também com mais sites e pastas dentro de /var/www/html, sem mudar o path de toda a aplicação e prejudicar o funcionamento do *git*?

**Considerações:** Se não ficou claro o suficiente, por favor, me avise que tentarei detalhar mais!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hospedar diversas aplicações em um servidor você precisa configurar VirtualHosts no Apache.

Com isso, você tem um site em cada pasta e aponta cada um dos domínios para um DirectoryRoot diferente.

Criando um arquivo de configuração para o siteA. Este arquivo deve ficar em `/etc/apache2/sites-available/sitea.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@sitea.com.br
    ServerName sitea.com.br
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sitea/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sitea-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sitea-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Crie a pasta e faça o upload do `sitea` em `/var/www/sitea/public` conforme definido na configuração `DocumentRoot`

Agora faça o apontamento do seu domínio (sitea.com.br no exemplo) para o IP deste servidor.

E habilite o website com o comando `a2ensite sitea`. Lembrando que este comando espera receber o nome do arquivo de configuração que está no diretório `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

Repita o processo para quantos VirtualHosts precisar.

Ah! E, se precisar de um subdominio pode utilizar quantos quiser com a configuração de ServerAlias, mas não esqueça de configurar a zona de DNS do seu domínio. Exemplo:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@sitea.com.br
    ServerName sitea.com.br
    ServerAlias www.sitea.com.br teste.sitea.com.br
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sitea/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sitea-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sitea-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Veja este tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-configurar-apache-virtual-hosts-no-ubuntu-14-04-lts-pt

Comment: Vou dar uma lida no article e volto ai para falar se deu certo. Valeu, amigo!

Comment: Considere instalar um Painel de Controlo par auxiliar na gestão. Existe uma solução gratuíta chamada [VestaCP](https://vestacp.com)

Comment: @CaiqueRomero obrigado pelas orientações, teve toda razão. Editei a resposta adicionando partes essenciais que ajudará a resolver o problema

Comment: Resolvido. Li o artigo, e os artigos dentro do artigo. Só preciso transferir os domínios e configurar DNS e essas coisas.